# can you use sd card/thumbdrive for app storage on chromebook?

Tags: chromebook, google-chrome-os

I have a Chromebox with 32 GB M.2 SSD, Chrome OS v97 numerous apps installed and Linux.
Apparently I can't install any more apps since it says 31.9 GB (of 32 GB) are in use

Is there any way that I can offload any chrome or Android apps, or the Linux stuff onto an SD card or USB thumbdrive?

Comment: 32GB is barely enough for 1 OS. Of course you can move your personal files to external media but not programs. Ubuntu currently needs a minimum of 25GB for just the system and a few apps, enough free space for temporaries and updates to avoid the risk of not being able to load the desktop (GUI). Much more is STRONGLY recommended. Chromebooks are to be use with ChromeOS, period, and ChromeOS is just a glorified web browser for which such small drives are acceptable. I wouldn't recommend any sort of dual-boot with less than 120-128GB nowadays and much more if Windows is in the equation.

Comment: Your best option is probably to [upgrade the SSD](https://www.mrmemory.co.uk/ssd-upgrades/asus/desktop/chromebox-3) but it may require reinstalling ChromeOS on your device. You should probably Google that before you start to make sure it is easy for you to do.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Are you sure your figures are appropriate for my scenario?  This is not a "dual boot" scenario, this is chromeos with Linux Crostini enabled, which is a supported and encouraged feature

Comment: I've mentioned Ubuntu (and dual-boot) above merely as an example. That the feature is officially supported and a container inside ChromeOS rather then an actual dua-boot is immaterial. It changes nothing about the feasibility of what you're asking and the space requirements for whatever you installed already. 32GB is ridiculously small nowadays.